# ERROR ITMS-90542: "Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value."

Tags: xcode, ios9

I cannot submit my ipa of a iOS9 hotfix to the appstore, this is the errors I get on the Application loader:

> ERROR ITMS-90542: "Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value. The key
>   'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in the Info.plist file in bundle
>   'Payload/PgapIos.app/GoogleMaps.bundle' contains an invalid value '(
>   "iPhoneSimulator" )'. Consider removing the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms
>   key from the Info.plist. If this bundle is part of a third-party
>   framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an
>   update to address this issue."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/PgapIos.app/GoogleMaps.bundle' does not contain a bundle
>   executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an
>   executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is
>   part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of
>   the framework for an update to address this issue."

I have xcode 7.0 (7A220)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and editing the plist file of googlemaps framework was not working for me, I solved it by removing the framework and installing it with cocoapods. [use this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en)

Comment: if library doesn't support cocoapods this solution will not work, I recommend @Marcus's answer.

Comment: If you're already using cocoapods for google maps, the problem might also be that you're using an old version. See my answer below, to update the google maps pod version.

Answer (score 22):

I just got these same warnings with the GoogleMaps bundle.  I did what the error messages recommended: Going to the offending info.plist file (in XCode) and deleting the keys that the error messages recommended.  This worked for me on my next attempt to upload my app to iTunesConnect

Comment: I am facing similar issue, but cannot find any key named: CFBundlePackageType. I am setting "Bundle OS Type code" to BNDL

Comment: If you control click the info.plist in Xcode you will see an option "Show Raw Keys / Values". Click that and the actual key names will appear and you should be able to find the ones in the error.

Comment: thanks @Marcus this helped me. "Executable file" turned into "CFBundleExecutable" which is the one the error explicitly mentioned

Answer (score 13):

ERROR ITMS-90542: "Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value

I am trying to upload a .ipa file to app store and I was getting the error 'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in the Info.plist iPhoneSimulator.

I have resolve this error. You need to update the GoogleMaps.bundle and GMSCoreResources.bundle info.plist.

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = {
"iPhoneSimulator"
},

Replace with iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = {
"iPhoneOS"
},

Answer (score 6):

I had a ton of trouble actually finding the Info.plist. This is NOT your project's .plist file. Instead, search your entire Xcode project using shift+command+f and search for whatever is invalid, i.e. search for "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error. I happened to be using `Carthage` to manage some framework dependencies.  The solution for me was to ensure I was not including any of the `dSYM` files that Carthage will generate for you into the app's resource bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It is a case issue in the items of

> CFBundleSupportedPlatforms

Yo can change it to something like:

> iphonesimulator

Fixed my issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing from cocoapods, it may be that you are using an older version of the Google Maps pod. I was using 1.10.1 and got this error. I did a `pod update GoogleMaps` and it went up to 2.2.0 ; and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved above error in my end Xcode 8. You need to update the GoogleMaps.bundle and GMSCoreResources.bundle info.plist.

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = { "iPhoneSimulator" },

Replace with iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = { "iPhoneOS" }

Thanks to @Anit kumar

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Replace with iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS in both 
GoogleMap.info -> info.plist and GSMCoreResources.bundle -> info.plist

Also remove REMOVE the following key entirely in both 
GoogleMap.bundle -> info.plist  and GSMCoreResources.bundle -> info.plist